# Don't want netbeans debugger to go to disassembly window

Tags: c, netbeans, gdb

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528) for C programming. Everytime I debug the program, for every printf and scanf (or probably every system calls) it opens up the disassembly window and goes through every assembly code. I simply want to watch variables and have nothing to do with the assembly code of such functions.
I think before netbeans 6.9 or so, it never happened and the debugging was smooth so as to simply print or scan on the standard input or output without going into the annoying assembly code. 
How do I simply disable it from going to the assembly code and debug as per lines of source code?

Comment: It's because you don't have the source for those functions. Simply don't step into the standard library functions (or any library you don't have built from source), just step over the call.

Comment: thx! it helped me a lot