# Debugging C++ in Netbeans

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans

I am very new to work c++ Programs with Netbeans IDE in Ubuntu. I wrote a simple Hello World Program and tried to debug it using step Into. When I Click Step Into Option From Debug Menu I got new window opened in the name of " Diassembly(main) " . The Debug process didn't reach my source code line at any way. I repeatedly click Step Into Function At last the process got end Without Tracing my source code line. But In the Debug output window I got the Correct Result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello";
    cout<<"World";
}
```

Why This process Control goes to the Diassembly (main) window ? How to rectify this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplication. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654524/dont-want-netbeans-debugger-to-go-to-disassembly-window

Comment: I tried the same thing with eclipse IDE. It says "No source available for "main() at 0x80486a3" "

Comment: I'm getting this problem too, on some projects (on another project I have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850200/why-are-my-variables-out-of-scope)   Did you find a solution in the end (other than "use Eclipse")?

Answer (score 3):

You must compile with `-g` option, otherwise the debugger won't be able to stop on a breakpoint. As for disassembling window - I can't reproduce that (I'm on Netbeans 7.4 in Ubuntu 13). You should just close the window if you don't need it.

Comment: How to change the compile settings as you said above ? I am very new to Netbeans. Can you please how to compile with -g option ?

Comment: @SmithDwayne - Netbeans calls `make` to compile, so you should have `Makefile` in your directory. Look inside this file - the `CFLAGS` variable (or similar) defines compilation flags.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to toggle a break point  in your code by clicking on the line number of the line you want to stop in source window, if you did not. Then hit Debug.
Don't step into function that you not build from source, just step over it.

Comment: I tried it . But I got the result as same as I get earlier.

Comment: I don't know how did you debug your program, maybe you did wrong procedure of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Pehaps that there is an answer here (i can't comment sorry)

["No source available for main()" error when debugging simple C++ in Eclipse with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324602/no-source-available-for-main-error-when-debugging-simple-c-in-eclipse-with)